# AJAX Query to Web Service in SharePoint on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am trying to have a button on a SharePoint form query the govt SAM web service.  Basically, I want to be able to manually enter a value in the form, click an HTML button, to query that value from the open form, and then fill out the rest of the fields automatically and save the record in a SP list.  I am just working on the query portion now. I have jquery embedded in my master page.

When I wrote all the logic in the browser console, everything works fine.  I cannot get it to mesh up with the button. I get this error in the console.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" which makes no sense.  Here is my script:

```
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
    var SAM_Title = document.getElementById('Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-
0177e6ddd247_$TextField').value;
    var URL = "https://api.data.gov/sam/v1/registrations/" + SAM_Title + 
"0000?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var SAM_AJAX = $.get(URL);
    var SAM_JSON = SAM_AJAX.responseText;
    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(SAM_JSON);
    var BusinessName = parse.sam_data.registration.legalBusinessname;
    var StreetAddress = 
parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.govtBusinessPoc.address.Line1;
    var City = parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.govtBusinessPoc.address.City;
    var ZIP = parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.govtBusinessPoc.address.ZIP;
}

</script>
```

Here is what I am putting in my script editor web part:

```
<html>
<script src="/SiteAssets/SAM_Query.js">
</script>
<body>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

where SAM_Query.js is the above mentioned script.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the difference between synchronous and asynchronous requests.

Comment: Check your tags to make sure they have closing tags. Could possibly be missing a closing `/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  The key was line 13 and cleaning up the syntax.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "jquery ready!" );
})

function samWebService() {

    SAM_Title = document.getElementById('Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField').value;
    console.log("DUNS: " + SAM_Title);
    URL = "https://api.data.gov/sam/v1/registrations/" + SAM_Title + "0000?api_key=xxxxxxxxx";
    console.log("URL: " + URL);
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
    SAM_AJAX = jQuery.get(URL);

    console.log("SAM JSON response: " + SAM_AJAX);
    SAM_JSON = SAM_AJAX.responseText;
    console.log(SAM_JSON);
    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(SAM_JSON);
    console.log(parsedJSON);
    BusinessName = parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.legalBusinessName;
    StreetAddress = parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.mailingAddress.Line1;
    City = parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.mailingAddress.City;
    ZIP = parsedJSON.sam_data.registration.mailingAddress.Zip;

    document.getElementById('Address_bc611d08-c16c-4ad9-a5b8-14388e176aba_$TextField').value=StreetAddress
    document.getElementById('City_dd99bc74-382f-406c-aec0-8dc196b2c8ef_$TextField').value = City
    document.getElementById('Business_x0020_Name_5eb60d17-9d0b-4243-92f5-81f5534e8bc0_$TextField').value = BusinessName
    document.getElementById('ZIP_e078f52b-a0bc-4c95-a622-a16d6491b017_$TextField').value = ZIP
};
```

And calling the function with a clickable link.

```
<script src="/siteassets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/test/SiteAssets/SAM_Query.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="samWebService();">Click Me!</a>
```